# Windows time update doesn't work properly

Tags: windows-10, time, date-time

In those days you don't want to set your system time manually. But even though my system is configured to do auto time updates the time is sometimes very inaccurate (more than a minute off). When I realize it I force Windows to "Update now" in the Internet Time Settings but often this update fails. What do you propose to do? My goal would be that I don't have to care about the time. My system shall care about it and keep it in sync.

Comment: Please take a look at the proposed duplicate question, and it will probably help you.  Personally, I find the default Internet time synchronization sources to be a bit unreliable, and I always change my source to `pool.ntp.org`.

Comment: Use time.nist.org - see the answer here:  https://superuser.com/questions/1214735/how-do-i-tell-windows-to-adjust-the-time-even-if-its-waaay-off/1219885#1219885