# How do I tell Windows to adjust the time even if it's waaay off?

Tags: windows-10, window, date

Apparently Windows 10 gets confused about what time it is - I'm pretty sure that my BIOS clock isn't getting reset, as it's just fine under Linux, and the date portion is fine it's just the hours that are like... 4 or 5 hours off.

When I right click on the taskbar clock and click `Adjust date/time`, `Set time automatically` is already turned on. But when I turn it off and then on again, my time gets updated to the correct time.

How do I tell Windows to do this kind of thing for me automatically at boot?

Comment: It sounds like Windows is unable to communicate with the NTP server your currently using.  You should verify if that is the case the modify your configuration accordingly..

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: When you setup the PC for the first time, did you select the right time zone default?

Comment: @TimmyJim yeah the timezone is fine - it shows up as the correct timezone in adjust date/time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 always showing wrong time (when dual-booting with Ubuntu)](https://superuser.com/questions/1174187/windows-10-always-showing-wrong-time-when-dual-booting-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Ramhound is correct in the comment above, that Windows is unable to communicate with the NTP server.

The first step to verifying this

Click on your clock

Click on Change time and date settings

Click on Internet Time

Click on Change Settings

Note the address of the NTP server listed (like pool.ntp.org)

Then click on your Windows icon and type CMD

When the command window is open, then type

```
ping pool.ntp.org
```

and see if you get a response.

If so, that will verify basic connectivity but not the NTP protocol itself.

If not, then you do not have connectivity to that server,
 so go back and try other NTP servers until you find one that works.

### --------------------------

All that being said, you could skip all that testing and simply change the NTP server address to

```
time.nist.gov
```

This is the primary NTP server address at the National Institutes of Science and Technology, Natioinal Bureau of Standards.  This server is proven to more reliable than the defaults that come preset in Windows.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't the problem, since turning it off and then on again works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to start a batch file e.g time_sync_start.bat , from the taskscheduler with admin rights, as trigger on login or boot :

> @ECHO OFF
>
> net start w32time
>
> w32tm /resync
>
> @ECHO OFF